# $p$-group and an normal subgroup, need help to start my solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, p-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group with |$G$|=$p^{n}$ with $p$ is prime and $n>1$.
Let's say that $N$ is a strict normal subgroup of $G$.

1. Prove there is an $x\in Z(G/N)$ of order $p$, i.e.  $x^{p}=e$ and $x \neq e$.
2. Prove that there exist a normal subgroup $M$  with $N\subset M\subset G$ and $[M:N]$=$p$.
3. Prove $G$ is soluble.

I wanted  to solve the above but I'm really sorry i can't come further then definitions.
I know it seems like there isn't a lot of effort in this post but I have really no clue how to start this. I looked here for some extra information but didn't find a post that could help me.
I would appreciate it if you could help me out so i can understand similair questions or understand how stuff with a p-group works.

I'm really sorry i will edit the question with my solutions that i found with your help :)

1. I got this hint :Since N⊊G is a strict normal subgroup, G/N is a nontrivial p-group, i.e. |G/N|=$p^{k}$ for some k∈N. This implies Z(G/N)≠{e} ,because if $G/N$ is a p-group then |Z(G/N)|>1 ,and Z(G/N) is again a p-group. Now it should be easy to find an element x∈Z(G/N) of order p.

My solution: from the above we know that $Z(G/N)$ has a order $p^{k}$ for a $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Let's take a $x\in Z(G/N)$ with order $s\in \mathbb{Z}$. This means that $x^{s}=e$. Now it follows that $p^{k}|s$. It's trivial that if $s=p$, $p^{k}|p$ so there exist an element with order $p$.

Comment: The first part is just asking you to prove that in a group of order $p^m > 1$ there exists an element of order $p$. You really should be able to do that by yourself. Then you can reasonably ask for help with the second part. (Actually, from the way it is phrased, you could just choose the identity element for $x$ in Part 1, but I am sure that they want you to prove that there is a non-identity element with $x^p=1$.)

Comment: alright i will try again

Comment: The solution to the first part is not quite correct - the order $s \in \mathbb{N}$ of $x$ has to divide the group order, i.e. $s \mid p^k$. Hence $s$ is itself a prime power $p^l$ with $l \in \mathbb{N}_0$. If you choose $x \neq e$, you get $l \neq 0$. Now you have an element $x$ of order $p^l$ and need to obtain an element of order $p$.

Comment: @mathmath If you know Cauchy's theorem then you may say that since $|Z(G/N)$ is a power of $p$ then there is an element of order $p$.

Comment: @Alexdanut While it is correct that one can apply Cauchy's theorem to get the solution for part 1, it seems rather excessive since any $y \in Z(G/N)$ with $y \neq e$ can be used to obtain an element of order $p$ by exponentiating.

Comment: @sebastian could you maybe change it so that I'm sure i understood it right

Comment: @mathmath I'm not quite sure what you mean by "change it". Do you understand the my comment about the first part? If you do, then you have an element $x \in Z(G/N)$ of order $p^l$ with $l \in \mathbb{N}$. Now think about what order elements of the form $x^n$ have, in particular for $n = p^r$ with $r \in \{1, \dots, l\}$.

Comment: If you can change the part where i'm fault?

Comment: @mathmath Which part of my first comment is not clear to you? I don't think it is helpful if I solve the exercise for you.

Comment: @SebastianSpindler I agree with you, I thought that maybe it would be useful for him to see a way that just makes use of a theorem that he (probably) learned

Answer (score 4):

I'll first post some hints here, but these are too long for a comment:

1. Since $N \subsetneq G$ is a strict normal subgroup, $G/N$ is a nontrivial $p$-group, i.e. $|G/N| = p^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies $Z(G/N) \neq \{e\}$ and $Z(G/N)$ is again a $p$-group. Now it should be easy to find an element $x \in Z(G/N)$ of order $p$.
2. Normal subgroups $M \subseteq G$ with $N \subseteq M$ and index $[M:N] = p$ correspond to normal subgroups $\tilde{M} \subseteq G/N$ with $|\tilde{M}| = p$.
3. Proceed by induction on $n$ and use the fact that for a normal divisor $M$ of $G$, $G$ is soluble if and only if both $M$ and $G/M$ are soluble.

EDIT: Some clarifications:

1. You should of course convince yourself why the given hints are true. The only nontrivial part of hint 1 is that $Z(G/N) \neq \{e\}$.
2. We have a bijection \begin{align*}\{M \subseteq G \text{ normal subgroup with } N \subseteq M\} &\to \{\tilde{M} \subseteq G/N \text{ normal subgroup}\} \\ M &\mapsto M/N. \end{align*}

Comment: thank you , I will put my answer in the question so you can see what i did with your hintts

Comment: @mathmath The bijection Sebastian Spindler gave in hint  2 is also called the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @drandran12 I think it is actually the fourth isomorphism theorem - the third one should be the one about $(G/N)/(M/N) \cong G/M$.